Get current list view url from list view action button LWC
Challenge: once list view action is called, the url changes to lwc components url reference and unable to get actual list view detailed url before.
Could see that there are options in vf page like vfRetURLInSFX, but in lwc how can we get that
Thanks in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
